# How to use Fubini's theorem to calculate Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm having some trouble with this problem.
Let n $\geq$ 1 and n is an integer. Use Fubini's theorem to calculate the $n$-th Lebesgue measure of this set:
$$\left\{ (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n: x_i \geq 0, i = 1, 2, \dots,  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq 1 \right\}$$

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: start with $n=2$ and $n=3$ and then obtain a general formula with what was told by Justpassingby.

Comment: @Marko good idea. Even $n=1$ (as an integral) is instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measure of a set is the integral of its indicator function. Write the $n$-dimensional integral of the indicator function of the set, then use Fubini to evaluate the integral as a succession of one-dimensional integrals.

As Marko's comment suggested, it is a good idea to start with specific values $n=1,2,3\ldots$ This will help you guess the right answer for general $n,$ which can then be computed by induction.

Comment: So, it just like a multiple integral?

Comment: Yes, it is; with the particularity that the function to integrate is the constant 1, and all the interesting behaviour is in the limits of integration.

Comment: *** Thanks! ***