# Find $n$-dimensional measure of set $A$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Problem.** Find $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $A$.
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be a set:

$$
A = \left\{ (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_{i}| \right) \leq 1 \right\}
$$

- *Exact same problem*. The same problem appears [[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619660/how-to-use-fubinis-theorem-to-calculate-lebesgue-measure)].

  - For $n = 1$, we have $0 \leq \lambda(A) \leq 1 \implies \lambda(A) \leq 1$.  It seems to be obvious to me.
  - For $n = 2$, we have $0 \leq \lambda(A) \leq 2 \implies \lambda(A) \leq 2$.
    Sqaure with $a = \sqrt{2}$.
- *Similar problem.*  I have noticed similar problem [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087350/find-lebesgue-measure-of-x-1-dots-x-n-in-mathbbrn-sum-i-1nx-i-n)], where $A$:
  $$
  A = \left\{ \left( x_1, x_2,  \ldots, x_{n} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n |x_{i}| : \forall |x_{i}| \leq 1\ \right\}.
  $$

Comment: Both problems are wrongly stated. In your problem, $A$ is supposed to be a set, but you have written it equal to a function, and somehow this function is less than 1. In the "similar problem", you have written $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$, with no restrictions on it. Then there is a forall sign that I cannot undestand. This leads me to guess that your issue is not with measure theory but with set notation

Comment: I understand your issue, I have the same feeling.

Sum in mine problem may have different measures.
For example, if $x_{i} = 0, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$ then measure is $0$.
At the same time, if $x_{1} = 1$ and the rest is zero, measure is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a probabilistic intepretation. Consider independent random variables $(u_k)_{k\in \{1,2,...n\}}$ s.t. $u_k:\Omega \to [-1,1]$ IID uniform. We have
$$F_{|u_1|}(z)=P(|u_1|\leq z)=P(\{u_1 \in [0,z]\}\cup\{u_1 \in [-z,0]\})=2\frac{z}{2}=z,\,z \in [0,1]$$
and by independence
$$\begin{aligned}P_n=P(|u_1|+|u_2|+...+|u_n|\leq 1)&=\int_{[0,1]^n}\mathbf{1}_{\{x:\sum x_k \leq 1\}}(x)dx=\\
&=\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,x_1]}\int_{[0,x_2]}(...)\int_{[0,x_{n-1}]}dx_n(...)dx_3dx_2dx_1\end{aligned}$$
So
$$\begin{aligned}n=1&\implies P_1=1\\
n=2&\implies P_2=2^{-1}\\
n=3&\implies P_3=(3\cdot 2)^{-1}\\
&(...)\\
n=k&\implies P_k=(k!)^{-1}\end{aligned}$$
Now to find the volume $V_n$ of $A$ (i.e. $\lambda(A))$ as we wanted, we solve the proportion
$$P_n:1=V_n:2^n\implies V_n=2^nP_n$$
where $\lambda([-1,1]^n)=2^n$.

Comment: The problem does not say anything about independence of $u_{k}$ 

I am not sure we can say sum of modules is the same as module of sum. 
For example, the following satisfies sum of modules, per inequality, but it does not satisfy module of sum.
$|\frac{1}{2}| + |\frac{1}{1}| \not \leq 1$

More over, why $P_{2} = 2^{-1}$? 
Shouldn't it be $P_{2}=2$ as the area is a square with $a=\sqrt{2}$.
The graph. [ [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cy%7C+%3C+1) ]

Comment: @limakzi the solution is not $P_n$, it's $V_n$. Essentially this is a monte carlo simulation for solving integrals. I also ran code and it matches the result